# How can I change the anchor for a MUI popover?

Tags: javascript, material-ui, popover

I have:

```
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const anchorRef = createRef()
  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const handleClick = useCallback(
    (event: MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent>>) => {
      setOpen(s => !s);
    },
    [anchorRef]
  );


  return (
    <SearchFormContainer ref={anchorRef}>
      <Popover
        open={open}
        anchorEl={anchorRef}
        onClose={handleClose}
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: 'bottom',
          horizontal: 'center',
        }}
      >
...
```

But this doesn't anchor it to the element that I want to anchor to. All the docs have it anchoring to the button that triggers the popover, but I want it to be anchored elsewhere. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `anchorEl` should be set to the actual `HTMLElement`, so pass `anchorRef.current`:

```
anchorEl={anchorRef.current}
```

In addition, replace `createRef()` with `useRef()` so that the same ref is persisted across renders.

Comment: But this doesn't position correctly. I need it to be moved over to the center

Comment: @Shamoon You should also replace `createRef()` with `useRef()`.

Comment: How would that work @Unmitigated?

Comment: @Shamoon If you use `createRef`, a new ref is created on each render and you assign `anchorRef.current` to the popover before React actually sets the ref. With `useRef`, the same ref is persisted across renders.

Comment: How would I set the ref then for an existing item?

Comment: @Shamoon What do you mean? `ref={yourRef}` is the standard way to do it.

Comment: But just keep in mind that with functional components, you should almost always be using `useRef`, not `createRef`.